# Altering Boolean string values using reflection does not work

Tags: java, string, reflection, boolean

I was experimenting with Java reflection and inlined Strings and came up with the result which I find confusing.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class HappyDebugging {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        defineTrueFalse();

        System.out.println("true is " + true); // why is it "true is true"?
        System.out.println("false is " + false);
        System.out.println(true);
        System.out.println(false);
        System.out.println("true");
        System.out.println("false");
        System.out.println("true is " + Boolean.valueOf(true));
        System.out.println("false is " + Boolean.valueOf(false));
        System.out.println("true is " + Boolean.valueOf("true"));
        System.out.println("false is " + Boolean.valueOf("false"));
    }

    static void defineTrueFalse() throws Exception{
        Field field = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set("true", new char[] {'f', 'a', 'l', 's', 'e'});
        field.set("false", new char[] {'t', 'r', 'u', 'e'});

        field = String.class.getDeclaredField("offset");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.setInt("true", 0);
        field.setInt("false", 0);

        field = String.class.getDeclaredField("count");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.setInt("true", 5);
        field.setInt("false", 4);
    }
}
```

Why are first two lines in the output are

```
true is true
false is false
```

I would expect them to be

```
true is false
false is true
```

Please note the output varies on different platforms.

Comment: Not sure what this Field thing is but I don't think you are overriding anything since the function (defineTrueFalse()) is void so it's still printing true as true (and false as false)

Comment: Seems like all you're doing is invoking undefined behavior by breaking  `String.class` internals.

Comment: @Cemre RTM http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html

Comment: @Cemre: He's not overriding anything. He is fiddling with the field values (`value`, `offset` and `count`) contained inside the `String` objects represented by the literals `"true"` and `"false"`.

Comment: Ah I see now. Sorry for misinterpreting the question. Please ignore my comment. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my compiler, those two lines get compiled to use the actual strings `"true is true"` and `"false is false"` (that is, no run-time concatenation occurs), so your reflective evil comes too late. You say that the output depends on the platform, so I guess some compilers must not perform this optimization.

Comment: Even if the compiler doesn't treat it as compile-time constants, the boolean values won't be affected by the reflection evil

Comment: that and the implementaion of `AbstractStringBuilder.append(boolean b)`

Answer (score 17):

this seems to be working....

```
String.valueOf(BooleanValue)
```

Answer (score 4):

`defineTrueFalse` has no effect so `"true is " + true` is treated as `"true is " + Boolean.toString(true)` thats why it give you result as `true is true`

Answer (score 3):

The answer is simple. These two lines

```
 System.out.println("true is " + true);
 System.out.println("false is " + false);
```

do the following.
1. the simple value of type boolean "true" ist converted into String which results in the string "true". The same for "false", and that's it

Answer (score 2):

Because you're messing with the content of interned String literals (in a way that will damn your soul to eternal suffering in the ninth circle of hell, I might add), but your first two lines concatenate boolean literals, not String literals. Nothing in `defineTrueFalse()` has any effect on the boolean values `true` and `false` (as opposed to the String literals `"true"` and `"false"`).

> Please note the output varies on different platforms.

But not for the first two lines, I'd wager. For the String-related stuff that may be, since the behaviour depends on the interning of String literals, which I don't think is guaranteed by the spec (thus, ninth circle of Hell).